# Check if data for update is same as before in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Table1`:

```
 ID | RefID |  Answer | Points | 
----+-------+---------+--------+
 1  |   1   |    1    |   5    | 
 2  |   1   |    2    |   0    | 
 3  |   1   |    3    |   3    | 
 4  |   2   |    1    |   4    |
```

I have a result set in temp table Temp1 with same structure and have update Table1 only if for refID answer and points have changed, otherwise there should be deletion for this record.

I tried:

```
update table1 
set table1.answer = temp1.answer,
    table1.points = temp1.points 
from table1 
join temp1 on table1.refid = temp1.refid 
where table1.answer != temp1.answer or table1.points != temp1.points
```

Here is a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60424/1/1

However this is not working and don't know how to add the delete condition.
Desired result should be if tables not the same ex. (second row answer 2 points3):

```
 ID | RefID |  Answer | Points | 
----+-------+---------+--------+
 1  |   1   |    1    |   5    | 
 2  |   1   |    2    |   3    | 
 3  |   1   |    3    |   3    | 
 4  |   2   |    1    |   4    |
```

if they are same all records with refID are deleted.

Explanation when temp1 has this data

```
     ID  | RefID |  Answer | Points | 
     ----+-------+---------+--------+
     12  |   1   |    1    |   5    | 
     13  |   1   |    2    |   0    | 
     14  |   1   |    3    |   3    |
```

**EDIT:** adding another id column questionid solved the update by adding this also in join.

Table structure is now:

```
 ID | RefID |  Qid |Answer | Points | 
----+-------+------+-------+--------+
 1  |   1   |  10  |  1    |   5    | 
 2  |   1   |  11  |  2    |   0    | 
 3  |   1   |  12  |  3    |   3    | 
 4  |   2   |  11  |  1    |   4    |
```

SQL for update is: (fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00f87/1/1) :

```
update table1 
set table1.answer = temp1.answer,
   table1.points = temp1.points 
from table1 
join temp1 on table1.refid = temp1.refid and table1.qid = temp1.qid 
where table1.answer != temp1.answer or table1.points != temp1.points;

SELECT ID, refid, answer, points 
FROM table1
```

How can I make the deletion case, if data is same ?

Comment: I think this should be `table1.answer=temp1.answer and table1.points!=temp1.points` shouldn't it? Otherwise, you'll have a Cartesian product here. You can move this to the join clause as well.

Comment: @scsimon answer can be also different

Comment: well sure @MasterYi but why wouldn't answer 1 update answer 3 then? that isn't what you want, is it?

Comment: @scsimon basicly i have to compare the 6 cells if they are the same( 3 under answer and 3 under points) order is always the same

Comment: How did answer 2 get 3 points? Where did you get that from? Why not 5 points? Why didn't it remain 0? The join on your temp doesn't make sense.

Comment: @scsimon it is filled from temp table which can have any numbers for answer and points [ 4 5; 3 5; 15 23] so 4 and 5 will go in first row etc..

Comment: Since `RefId` is not unique, you are going to have problems with it. If your table1 and also temp1 contains the same `RefId` more than once the result will be unpredictable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes i added another column and solved the update problem, now issue is if the data is the same i need to delete instead of update

Comment: Then you should edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled edited

Comment: And I've edited and undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first do the delete, and only then the update.
The reason for this is that once you've deleted all the records where the three columns are the same, your update statement becomes simpler - you only need the join, and no where clause:

```
DELETE t1
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN temp1 ON t1.refid = temp1.refid
          AND t1.qid = temp1.qid
          AND t1.answer=temp1.answer
          AND t1.points=temp1.points 

UPDATE t1 
SET answer = temp1.answer,
    points = temp1.points 
FROM table1 AS t1 
JOIN temp1 ON t1.refid=temp1.refid 
          AND t1.qid = temp1.qid
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more condition in the join to exactly match the column.Try this one.

```
update table1 
set table1.answer=temp1.answer,
    table1.points=temp1.points 
from
table1 join temp1 on table1.refid=temp1.refid and **table1.ID=temp1.ID**
where table1.answer!=temp1.answer or table1.points!=temp1.points
```

Comment: id on temp can be anything

Comment: adding additional column for this solved the problem for update ty for the idea

Answer (score 0):

I think from what i understood that you need to use id instead of refid or both if id is unique